# Apple captive portal detection does not pop up web sheet browser

Tags: macos, iphone, ipad, ios

I'm an engineer developing a captive portal system for use at hotels.  I know Apple devices do captive portal detection upon joining a wireless network to see if the user is behind a captive portal by attempting to load http://www.apple.com/library/test/success.html.  If this URL does not load, or is redirected, the device assumes it is behind a captive portal and loads up the terms or login page in a websheet browser.

The problem is that we are properly redirecting these requests, but no Apple devices I test with present the websheet browser.  I'm wondering if we need to provide a wispr response, or some additional information.  Has anyone else had experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

> Apple devices do captive portal detection upon joining a wireless network to see if the user is behind a captive portal by attempting to load http://www.apple.com/library/test/success.html.

It is no longer the right case. The url now begins with `captive.apple.com`, followed by unique generated path.

> The problem is that we are properly redirecting these requests, but no Apple devices I test with present the websheet browser. I'm wondering if we need to provide a wispr response.

Yes, you have. You ve got it. This is the 2nd half of the matter.